# QGIS Convert SHP to KML keep all attributes

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, kml

I am trying to convert a SHP to KML in QGIS and want to keep all the attribute fields. As far as I can tell when you do this operation, you can only choose 2 fields (DescriptionField and NameField). Is there a way to do the conversion and keep all attributes?